# Object Required Error when referencing Excel Objects

Tags: excel, vbscript

Below is the VBScript code for deleting the duplicates from one excel workbook and then copying it to another, when I run it I'm getting an error;

> Object required:Activesheet

This is the code:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")    

' Open the workbook
Set objWorkbook1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\vijendra\Desktop\duplicates.xlsx")

Macro

Sub Macro1()
  activesheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns=Array(), Header=xlYes
End Sub

'Opening the 2nd workbook
Set objworkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\vijendra\Desktop\test2.xlsx")

'Set to True or False, whatever you like
objExcel.Visible = True

'Select the range on Sheet1 you want to copy 
objWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1").usedrange.Copy

'Paste it on sheet1 of workbook2, starting at A1
objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

'Activate Sheet2 so you can see it actually pasted the data
objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript doesn't support implicit use of the application object. You have to use it explicitly. VBScript also doesn't support named arguments (`name:=value`) or Excel built-in constants (`xlYes`). Change this line:

```
activesheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns=Array(), Header=xlYes
```

into this:

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Array(), 1
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for the suggestion but its not working for me.Its just copying between excel wookbooks but it not deleting the duplicates.

Comment: @Supriya As it is you're passing an empty array into the method. You need to fill the array with the indexes of the columns from which you want duplicates removed, e.g. `Array(1,2,3)` for the first 3 columns. Or you could call the method without parameters. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for reference.