# How do I create a ListTemplate object (Word) in VBS?

Tags: vba, vbscript

My Main question is in VBS I want a numbered list in my word document that I can restart. When I do `currDoc.ListParagraphs(1).Range.Style = "List_Number 1"` I get the numbered list but I can't restart this list. I just need to know how to restart the numbered list not how to detect when to restart.

I have tried to use ListTemplates but I can't seem to make it work. Either I get an error when I do this...

`Set myLt = ActiveDocument.ListTemplates(3)
Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=myLt`

saying something is wrong with the syntax.

or I get no error but this does nothing...

`Set myLt = ActiveDocument.ListTemplates(3) 
Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate=myLt`

I'm new to VBS and don't know how to do numbered lists so please be patient with me. Thanks!

**Edit (20/02/2019)**

```
            Set myLt = ListGalleries(2).ListTemplates(3)
            currDoc.ListParagraphs(i).Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate myLt, false
```

I did the above and didn't work. I want `currDoc.ListParagraphs(i).Range.Style = "List_Number 1` to become a ListTemplate object. How to do this?

Comment: you cannot use named parameters in VBScript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vb Script on excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428050/vb-script-on-excel)

Comment: @GeertBellekens I tried the link you gave but read my new edit to the question. I want to convert this "List_Number 1" into a ListTemplate object so I can restart the numbering. How would I do this?