# Getting AdvancedFilter method of range class failed error while coping unique data from one excel to another

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have attached the snippet of the excel file where column B is the desired Output. This similar logic worked in macro but as per our requirement, we need to build a VBScript for it. Below is my code

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible = True
Set inputExcelWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\...\Test1.xlsx")
Set inputExcelSheet = inputExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet


inputExcelSheet.Range("A2:A11").AdvancedFilter _
xlFilterCopy,,inputExcelSheet.Range("B2"),True

inputExcelWorkbook.save
inputExcelWorkbook.close
```

Snippet of the Excel File
[image: screenshot]

Comment: First try putting it all on one line. Next, split out all those nested statements into multiple statements. i.e. `Set c1 = RetroExcelSheet.Cells(StartRow, 17)`. Then you can find out exactly which one is causing the issue

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, I am very new to vbscript. I will try my best. Thanks a lot for the help :D

Comment: Set c1 = RetroExcelSheet.Cells(StartRow, 17)
  Set c2 = RetroExcelSheet.Cells(LastRow, 17)

RetroExcelSheet.Range(c1, c2).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=OrgExcelSheet.Range("A3"), Unique:=True
Hi @Nick.McDermaid I did what you just suggested. I am getting the same error. The error is at character 58 which is Action:=

Comment: You did well. Ok so now I remember that none of those constants exist in VBScript unless you include them - i.e. `xlFilterCopy` has no value - find out the real value (from within VBA) and use that instead. Also I don't think named parameters work in VBScript either

Comment: So try `RetroExcelSheet.Range(c1, c2).AdvancedFilter(2,, OrgExcelSheet.Range("A3"), True)`

Comment: Sorry I gotta go to sleep now good luck

Comment: Ignore the advice about removing `_` it's perfectly [acceptable syntax in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37565683/692942) known as a [Statement Break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee198844(v=technet.10)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object Required Error when referencing Excel Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428050/vb-script-on-excel)

Comment: I will edit this question so it becomes much simpler to understand

Comment: In your latest code snippet your need to not use constants. You need to use ‘2’. Also you need to surround the arguments in brackets. Look at my code snippet.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It worked for me but without using the parenthesis. I have put that in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, My issue was resolved when instead of using xlFilterCopy , I used "2" as per @nick.McDermaid suggestion

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible = True
Set inputExcelWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\...\Test1.xlsx")
Set inputExcelSheet = inputExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet


inputExcelSheet.Range("A2:A11").AdvancedFilter _
2,,inputExcelSheet.Range("B2"),True

inputExcelWorkbook.save
inputExcelWorkbook.close
```